# Merge Multiple Feature Branches

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

**Left Local, Right Remote**

[image]

I have already done the following

```
git checkout main
git pull --rebase
```

I would like to add `C2`-`C7` onto `main`.

I can accomplish this with `git cherry-pick C2 C3 ...` but doing so then requires me to use `git branch -f side1 HEAD~5` to then move the branch.

The tool I am using to practice says they used 6 steps. My solution in total takes 7.

How can I do this with less commands?

Here is the desired end result

[image]

I am accomplishing this in the following way

```
git cherry-pick C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
git branch -f side1 HEAD~5
git branch -f side2 HEAD~3
git branch -f side3 HEAD
git push
```

Comment: Perhaps they aren't counting the first checkout of main.

Comment: It's not necessary to move `side1`, `side2` and `side3` to the new heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very neatly and easily by issuing a series of `rebase --onto` commands. (Remember, rebase is basically just a bunch of cherry picks.) The syntax is:

```
git rebase --onto new-ancestor one-before-first-commit branch-to-rebase
```

So first, use `rebase --onto` to say "rebase just the last commit of `side1` onto `main`." So that takes care of C2. Note that `side1` has moved along with the new copy of C2; it now comes after `main` as in the picture.

Then, use `rebase --onto` to say "rebase `side2` as far back as C3 (i.e. C3 and C4) onto `side1`." So that takes care of two more commits, C3 and C4, and `side2` has moved.

Then use `rebase --onto` to say "rebase `side3` as far back as C5 (i.e. C5 and C6 and C7) onto `side2`." So that takes care of three more commits, and `side3` has moved.

When you are done, `main` will not have moved, but C2-C7 will come after it, under the name `side3`. The problem wants you to move `main`, so just check it out and merge `side3`.

So, I'll prove that this works. I started with this reconstruction of your initial situation:

```
* 43e5ea4 (HEAD -> main) c8
| * aebbfd9 (side1) c2
|/  
| * 902cad2 (side2) c4
| * d14f4dd c3
|/  
| * 5969ebd (side3) c7
| * 30e2d68 c6
| * cc70cb1 c5
|/  
* 8bad1ce c1
* e0ff3ef c0
```

Then my solution goes:

```
git rebase --onto main side1~1 side1
git rebase --onto side1 side2~2 side2
git rebase --onto side2 side3~3 side3
git switch main
git merge side3
```

I ended up with

```
* 90a16a1 (HEAD -> main, side3) c7
* 0e0a872 c6
* 5d402a6 c5
* 9255c63 (side2) c4
* 1397347 c3
* 17c1689 (side1) c2
* 43e5ea4 c8
* 8bad1ce c1
* e0ff3ef c0
```

which is just what they said they wanted on the local! Now `git push` (with force?) to get `main` mirrored onto the remote and you're done — in exactly six steps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are no conflicts.

```
git checkout main
git merge side1 side2 side3
git rebase --onto C8 C8 main
```

The 2nd and 3rd commands are not supported on https://learngitbranching.js.org/, so you need to construct the log graph in a real repository to have a test.